# How can I create Tether (USDT) wallet in pywallet?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

According to `pywallet` documentation it is as easy as pie to create a wallet on blockchain for btc, eth, etc:

```
# create_btc_wallet.py

from pywallet import wallet

# generate 12 word mnemonic seed
seed = wallet.generate_mnemonic()

# create bitcoin wallet
w = wallet.create_wallet(network="BTC", seed=seed, children=1)

print(w)
```

And its output will be something like:

```
$ python create_btc_wallet.py

{
  "coin": "BTC",
  "seed": "guess tiny intact poet process segment pelican bright assume avocado view lazy",
  "address": "1HwPm2tcdakwkTTWU286crWQqTnbEkD7av",
  "xprivate_key": "xprv9s21ZrQH143K2Dizn667UCo9oYPdTPSMWq7D5t929aXf1kfnmW79CryavzBxqbWfrYzw8jbyTKvsiuFNwr1JL2qfrUy2Kbwq4WbBPfxYGbg",
  "xpublic_key": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcEhoTt7d7qLjtMaE7rrACt42otGYdhv4dtYzwK3RPkfJ4nEjpFQDdT8JjT3VwQ3ZKjJaeuEdpWmyw16sY9SsoY68PoXaJvfU",
  "wif": "L1EnVJviG6jR2oovFbfxZoMp1JknTACKLzsTKqDNUwATCWpY1Fp4",
  "children": [{
     "address": "1E3btRwsoJx2jUcMnATyx7poHhV2tomL8g",
     "path": "m/0",
     "xpublic_key": "xpub69Fho5TtAbdoXyWzgUV1ZYst9K4bVfoGNLZxQ9u5js4Rb1jEyUjDtoATXbWvAcV8cERCMMnH8wYRVVUsRDSfaMjLqaY3TvD7Am9ALjq5PsG",
     "wif": "KysRDiwJNkS9VPzy1UH76DrCDizsWKtEooSzikich792RVzcUaJP"
 }]
}
```

My question is how I can create a valid `Tether` wallet on blockchain? Is there any other library that could solve this issue? Or any guidance to do it with pywallet?